# Why am I not seeing all of my in-app product details when doing an inventory check?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I've seen similar posts about this sort of problem but this is where my problem differs..

I have posted my APK to the alpha channel, I have checked and I am sending all 6 of the in-app products when doing my inventory check (see below).

```
public void getProductDetails() {
    if (mHelper == null || !storeSetup) return;
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Issue> issueList = OrmLiteIssueDAO.getInstance().getAllIssues(false);
    for (Issue issue : issueList) {
        if (!issue.isFreeIssue() && issue.getBillingId() != null && !issue.getBillingId().isEmpty() && !issue.getBillingId().equals("null")) {
            skuList.add(issue.getBillingId());
        }
    }
    List<Subscription> subscriptionsList = OrmLiteSubscriptionDAO.getInstance().getAllSubscriptions();
    for (Subscription subscription : subscriptionsList) {
        if (subscription.getSubscriptionSku() != null  && !subscription.getSubscriptionSku().isEmpty() && !subscription.getSubscriptionSku().equals("null")) {
            skuList.add(subscription.getSubscriptionSku());
        }
    }
    if (skuList.size() > 0) {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGotInventoryListener);
    }
    skuList.clear();
    issueList.clear();
    subscriptionsList.clear();
}
```

The problem is I am only getting 3 products back, the 3 products I have coincidently purchased.

The in-app products were created and made active 6/3/2015, it is now 10 days later so it's not a propagation issue and I can purchase all 6 products in my app.

I just cannot get any details for products that haven't been purchased.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

The inventory listener looks like:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        if (mHelper == null || !storeSetup) return;
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }
        if (inventory != null) {
            List<Issue> issues = OrmLiteIssueDAO.getInstance().getAllIssues(false);
            for (Issue issue : issues) {
                SkuDetails issueDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails(issue.getBillingId());
                if (issueDetails != null) {
                    issue.setIssuePrice(issueDetails.getPrice());
                }
                OrmLiteIssueDAO.getInstance().saveIssueToDB(issue);
            }
            List<Subscription> subscriptionsList = OrmLiteSubscriptionDAO.getInstance().getAllSubscriptions();
            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptionsList) {
                SkuDetails subDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails(subscription.getSubscriptionSku());
                if (subDetails != null) {
                    subscription.setSubscriptionPrice(subDetails.getPrice());
                }
                OrmLiteSubscriptionDAO.getInstance().saveSubscriptionToDB(subscription);
            }
            issues.clear();
            subscriptionsList.clear();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What does your got inventory listener look like?

Comment: @nasch added it to question

Comment: If you've verified that `getAllIssues` and `getAllSubscriptions` return what they're supposed to, then I don't see where you're doing anything wrong.  Sorry!